# Laravel Email in Job Queue not working except sync

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.8, I configured an email containing the invoice sent to user after they place an order.
Email is delivered when set `QUEUE_DRIVER=sync` but when I set it to redis/database and I run the `php artisan queue:work redis --tries=5` it shows the queue is processed

> Processing: Modules\Checkout\Mail\Invoice
> Processed:  Modules\Checkout\Mail\Invoice

succesfully and no entry in the failed_jobs either.

CODE:
**Modules\Checkout\Jobs\SendInvoiceEmail.php**

```
    class SendInvoiceEmail implements ShouldQueue
    {
      use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

      public $order;
      public function __construct(Order $order)
      {
        $this->order = $order;
      }

      public function handle()
      {
        Mail::to($this->order->customer_email)
              ->send(new Invoice($this->order));
      }
    }
```

And this is the **Modules\Checkout\Mail\Invoice.php**

```
class Invoice extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $order;

    public function __construct($order)
    {
        $this->order = $order;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->subject('New order: ', ['id' => $this->order->id]))
            ->view("emails.invoice");
    }

}
```

Then I am dispatching it in the Controller after Order created
`SendInvoiceEmail::dispatch($order);`

Can anyone point out if I've missed anything and what I am doing wrong?

I've done the `php artisan config:cache and clear:cache` restarted the server.

This works just as expected if I set `QUEUE_DRIVER=sync` in .env instead of `QUEUE_DRIVER=redis or database`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thing is `.env` or `config.php` both configurations should work normally.
My main issue was the application would save these settings from `.env` or `config.php` to *database*. then for the next time it looked in database for these smtp configs and anything other than `sync` tends to fail.
I don't know why it was configured so I removed and the issue was resolved

Answer (score 2):

I had that problem too and solve it putting a key in the `config/mail.php` file
in `mailers['smtp']` I add `local_domain` equals to my domain (`example.com`)

The reason is the Swift Mailer class can use this key to put in the HELO field of the email. If you use `QUEUE=sync` the framework uses the domain in env file, but when you use a different queue it doesn't cache the domain.

Comment: that's interesting. thanks for pointing that out. I will try this if this solves my problem

Comment: Didn't work for me